# get innerHTML from DOM using cheerio

Tags: html, meteor, cheerio

This Meteor server code tries to extract the innerHTML from a html string using `cheerio` package but the error says that the `elements` has no method 'size'

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks

here is the html;

```html
<span class='errorMsg'>some text </span>



message: (html, typeMsg) => {
      let $ = cheerio.load(html);
      const selection = 'span.' + typeMsg;
      const elements = $(selection);
      return elements.size() > 0 ? elements.get(0).innerHTML.trim() : '';
    }
```

Comment: How about `elements.get(0).text().trim()`?

Comment: Or: `elements.get(0).html().trim()`?

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock that gave "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'text'"

Comment: Why do you need to check the size/length here?

Answer (score 5):

```js
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var $ = cheerio.load('<b>hello</b> world');

// innerHTML
$('body').html()
// <b>hello</b> world

// outerHTML
$.html($('body'))
// <body><b>hello</b> world</body>

// innerText
$('body').text()
// hello world
```

docs: https://api.jquery.com/html/#html1

Answer (score 4):

After few trials and errors and trying to understand the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio#eq-i-), which cloud benefit from some more explanations.

**Option 1**

```
  const element = $(selection).eq(0);
  return element ? element.text().trim() : '';
```

**Option 2**

```
  const element = $(selection).get([0]);
  return element ? element.children[0].data.trim() : '';
```

I used option 1 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

My HTML looked like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
  <b>John Smith</b><br />
  <i>Head of Widgets</i><br />
  Google<br />
  Maitland, FL<br />
  123-456-7890<br />
  <a
    href="mailto:example@example.com"
    >example@example.com</a
  >
</div>
```

I wanted to extract the inner html of the div in the context of an "each" loop, so I used this code:

`$(this).html()`

Which returned

```
  <b>John Smith</b><br />
  <i>Head of Widgets</i><br />
  Google<br />
  Maitland, FL<br />
  123-456-7890<br />
  <a
    href="mailto:example@example.com"
    >example@example.com</a
  >
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have much to do with OP's code.